# How to extract the last name in an array of a full name?

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

Suppose I have a full name in a bash array, I want to robustly extract the last name and non last name (the first name and middle name if exists). For example, I show the following three examples to indicate the complexity of this problem.

```
x1=(John von Neumann)
x2=(Michael Jeffrey Jordan)
x3=(Michael Jordan)
```

Does anybody have a good way to extract the last name and the non last name? Thanks.

Comment: the last name `+` non last name = a full name? it means you want to extract the full name?

Comment: try: `\(([^)]*)` on a global match

Comment: "Robust" is something you aren't going to get.  Consider the all-times favourite [Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas de la Vallée-Poussin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Jean_de_la_Vallée-Poussin). :)

Comment: This is the kind of question where I just mention [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and suggest that you do not try to parse names – if possible and necessary, obtain surnames during data entry. While it would be possible to parse the majority of names for a specific culture, you will always have some percentage of errors.

Comment: @Cyrus sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you put every single name in a separate array. The more flexible way is to use a regular expression. In plain english the regex says: 
- either the last name starts with a lowercase char followed by a number of alphabetic characters and spaces
- or the last name follows the last space in the string.

Take at look at this:

```
#!/bin/bash

x1=(John von Neumann)
x2=(Michael Jeffrey Jordan)
x3=(Michael Jordan)
x4=(Charles-Jean Etienne Gustave Nicholas de la Vallée-Poussin)

regex="[[:space:]]([a-z]+.*|[A-Z][^[:space:]]+)$"

for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  eval name=\${"x"$i[@]}
  if [[ $name =~ $regex ]]; then
    fullname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo $fullname
  fi
done
```

Comment: This looks good. What about the non surname part? Can both surname and non surname be represented in the same regex so that one can use BASH_REMATCH[1] and BASH_REMATCH[2] to extract both?

Comment: The expression ${name:0:${#name}-${#BASH_REMATCH}} will give you the first part, without even changing the regex.

Comment: What about "James Van Ness"?